# Installed 2nd Bitcoin client and invalidated blockchain progress

Tags: blockchain, synchronization

over the last couple of days I synchronized the block chain on an old version of Bitcoin QT where I still had funds in my wallet. It started out 90 weeks behind, then over the course of 4 days updated until it had 23 more weeks to go. At this point any progress stopped, seemingly getting stuck for 24 hours or longer and I couldn't find a solution to make it continue its synchronization.

I then installed Unlimited Bitcoin since I heard that new clients would synchronize much faster. I assumed that both clients would build their block chain separately from each other but the Unlimited Bitcoin installation corrupted any progress that Bitcoin QT had made and upon starting it the next time, it had to re-synchronize now being more than 200 weeks behind.

Unlimited Bitcoin however seems to refer to QT's progress status, also being 200+ weeks behind and not updating any quicker.

What would be the fastest way to get the blockchain up to date on my hard drive in a way that the funds on my QT wallet can be used?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

BU might have changed their default installation directory, but I doubt it. Then it sounds to me that you were running two copies of Bitcoin software working with the same blockchain data. Even when not running them at the same time, I'm not surprised that this might corrupt the block data. (If you've run them at the same time, no wonder at all, although I thought there was a lock in place to prohibit that.)

1. Don't run more than one Bitcoin software from the same directory.
2. Pick whatever flavor you may choose to run, install a current version of that.
3. Wait until synchronization is finished. Later blocks take longer than earlier blocks due to more content.